# warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf lookup error for "root". error configuring MySQL lookups to a database on a remote server

Tags: postfix

I am facing the above mentioned warning, and I do not know why. The same configuration works well for one of the other server. Can anyoone please guide? Ubuntu 16.04

```
Sep 16 07:45:34 cs postfix/cleanup[17129]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf lookup error for "root"
Sep 16 07:45:34 cs postfix/cleanup[17129]: warning: 65E41260A77: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 16 07:45:35 cs postfix/pickup[16899]: warning: 664DD260A77: message has been queued for 1 days
```

`postconf -n`

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_percent_hack = no
append_at_myorigin = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
disable_dns_lookups = yes
fallback_relay =
home_mailbox = Maildir/
ignore_mx_lookup_error = yes
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 51200000
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
mydomain = ourdomain.com
myhostname = cs.ourdomain.com
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydestination, ourdomain.com
relayhost = [mail.ourdomain.com]
relocated_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relocated
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_inet_interfaces check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_security_options =
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access reject_unknown_sender_domain warn_if_reject reject_unverified_sender
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
swap_bangpath = no
transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_transport_mapping.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

`mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf`

```
user = postfix
password = password
dbname = postfix
table = alias
select_field = goto
where_field = address
hosts = host_ip
```

Comment: If your comment means that the database is hosted on a different server, that's what's missing from the configuration. I'm guessing the host where it works has the database locally.

Comment: yes database is on different server. yes the database is locally configured.

Comment: Have you checked the logs of your SQL server for error messages?

Comment: So your actual question is "how do I configure MySQL lookups to a database on a remote server?" Probably [edit] that into the question too. Again, your question should be complete and self-contained.

Comment: @Gerald yes, no errors related to the mentioned server/issue. connectivity with database server is ok. after observing in mail.log the following error " Host 'host_ip' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts' ", 
i did 'flush hosts'. but still cant find anything in mysql error log.

Comment: any help would be highly appreciated. i am stuck and unable to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem (localhost server though). Turned out somewhere along the line localhost translated from 127.0.0.1 to ::1 in some update I ran. Hard coded 127.0.0.1 in all my *.cf files in postfix (cd /etc/postfix && sed -i 's|localhost|127.0.0.1|g' *.cf)

> mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf

user = mail_sql_user

password = mail_sql_password

hosts = 127.0.0.1

dbname = mail

table = alias

select_field = goto

where_field = address

additional_conditions = and active = '1'